# Un-install JRE on Windows Server 2008

Tags: java, windows-server-2008

Not a Java person, so forgive this simple question, but on our Windows Server 2008 Enterprise server we have the following Java installations:

[image]

My understanding is that this is the JRE - shown as *Java (TM) 6 Update 37 (64-bit)* above I believe - and the JDK.

If I un-install the JRE will that leave the JDK intact and have no adverse effect?

Comment: You may lose some OS integration stuff such as being able to double click jars to run Java applications, run applets in a browser and use Java webstart. But since it is a server, that shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can surely uninstall and start working with JDK without any issues. Just don't forget to update JAVA_HOME and path variables accordingly.

Please refer to [this](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Setting+the+JAVA_HOME+Variable+in+Windows) page for steps of how to setup JAVA_HOME and path